# How to Organize my Photo Albums?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, gallery

I want to organize my photo galleries.
**Photos** > Personal > Professional

For each sub page, I want to organize the photo albums with thumbnails. eg *Personal > [thumbnails image with dimensions 210x180]*, also I want to describe it with the album title *[e.g. Paris]*, and how many photos has this album *[e.g. 28 photos]*.

When viewing this album, I want to display the photos for each album [like this](http://photogallerycreator.com/grand-flagallery/chocolate-skin/).

I think that the solution is to use taxonomies, but I tried and didn't have the result that I want. Also, I installed the plugin [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/), but still did not understand how to do what I want. Any proposal or direction?

Comment: Sorry, but your Question is a bit confusing. Where does this galleries are coming from? What is **Photos**? A custom post type? You are showing a Flash gallery as example... [Search here](http://codecanyon.net/category/wordpress/galleries)...

Comment: Yes, is a bit confusing because i can't upload a photo - wireframe, for that i want. Photos (page) is the first child of navigation menu, photos has two others children : personal (category) and Professional (category).

Comment: Actually, i want that thing that described in the following link  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/post-photo-galleries. I'm sorry I have not explained properly in my first post.

Comment: Some suggestions so you can work better with WP: 1) Take a look at the documentation, usually referred as [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page). So, you'll understand what is what in the eco-system. . . 2) It is possible to manage albums just with native features. . . 3) But you can research for themes that oriented to your area, [free](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) or premium. . . 4) And search for the [right plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=photo+albums+gallery&sort=) -important: recently updated ones and with small bug reports in the support page.

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for the answer. 1) The documentation is my bible. I read and often consult. 3) I don't want to research for themes, because i create my own. 4) I try to use less plugins for the reason that you explained to me. But, i want some directions of code to create and organize my photography albums. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

General idea based on the use of regular Posts, not [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) (which is what the plugin CPT-UI is about):

- one parent **Category** *-Photos*
- under it, the needed **sub-categories** *-Personal, Professional, etc*
- one post corresponds to one **Album** *-Vacations 2012, News Coverage, etc*
- upload all images of the Album into the post, put **titles, descriptions and ordering**
- use the **[`[gallery]`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)** shortcode to display the images
- the Gallery shortcode can be used in one page or post to display images of **another post/page**, check the **`id`** attribute
- use the **[Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)** to create different views for each Category (check the item `Category display`)

Comment: All these time, I did various experiments for the result. I did the conversions : **Photos** from _category_ to _page_, also i did that for the sub-menu : **Personal** and **Professional** for _category_ to _pages_. But this is not worked correct. For ex i want this : http://popcritics.com/books, and for this purpose i thought to use the plugin of **Custom post types**. For your proposal every time i will create a custom post and i transship it to category. Every post will have the permalinks to the image gallery. Thanks for the help, i will look in the coming hours and i will be back.

Comment: After days, deal again with this project. I want your help. The basic idea is to display all these with categories. **Category** - _Photos_ -> **Sub Category** - _Personal_ and **Sub Category** - _Professional_. Also, i want some extra custom fields like, **The title of Album** and  the **The number of photos**. All these things can be describe with the category.php? Videlicet, Ι must create except the **page.php** the **category.php**? I ask because I have not yet done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think that it is possible to do that with the custom post types, also i think that i need to create a custom page template for this. And all this thinking because i have so many categories, and for each one i want some extra fields like "The title of album" and "the number of photos" What is your opinion or advance? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the best way to deal with lots of categories. If nothing comes out of a [reseach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bmany+%2Bcategories), maybe you should open a new Question.

Comment: I will read all of these, and i hope to find the solution, otherwise i will open a new Question and i will try to be as informative as possible. Thanks for the help.